# Can't view CSV with Shinydashboard app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm just starting to learn shiny, and I've been having an issue with just viewing the uploaded csv. I was able to view the data when I didn't have a sidebar menu, but now that I am trying to expand on my app with other tabs, the data does now show up. Is there something wrong with my formatting? My code is attached, and it could be used for any csv. Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=400*1024^2) 

data<- read.csv("shiny.app.data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')

ui <- dashboardPage(skin="red",
  dashboardHeader(title="PRIZM Segment Analysis", titleWidth=350),
  dashboardSidebar(width=350, 
                   sidebarMenu(menuItem("Segment Counts and Summaries", tabname="segments", icon=icon("pie-chart")),
                   menuItem("Raw Data", tabname="raw", icon=icon("book")),
                   menuItem("Plots", tabname="plots", icon=icon("line-chart")))),               
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="segments",
                box(DT::dataTableOutput("test"), width = 12, status="success", solidHeader = TRUE)))

))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  is.num<- sapply(data, is.numeric)
  data[is.num] <-lapply(data[is.num], round,2)

  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
                datatable(data,
                extensions = c('ColReorder','Buttons'),
                options = list(colReorder = list(realtime = FALSE),scrollX = TRUE,dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = I('colvis'), list(scrollX = TRUE)),
                rownames=FALSE,
                class = 'display cell-border', width=15)


    })
    }

    shinyApp <- shinyApp(ui, server)
    runApp(shinyApp, launch.browser=TRUE)
```

Comment: You just want to view any csv in your machine - no uploading feature right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo in your code in `tabName` (notice the capital N) within the `menuItem`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=400*1024^2) 

data<- read.csv("shiny.app.data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')

ui <- dashboardPage(skin="red",
  dashboardHeader(title="PRIZM Segment Analysis", titleWidth=350),
  dashboardSidebar(width=350, 
                   sidebarMenu(menuItem("Segment Counts and Summaries", tabName="segments", icon=icon("pie-chart")),
                   menuItem("Raw Data", tabName="raw", icon=icon("book")),
                   menuItem("Plots", tabName="plots", icon=icon("line-chart")))),               
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="segments",
                box(DT::dataTableOutput("test"), width = 12, status="success", solidHeader = TRUE)))

))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  is.num<- sapply(data, is.numeric)
  data[is.num] <-lapply(data[is.num], round,2)

  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
                datatable(data,
                extensions = c('ColReorder','Buttons'),
                options = list(colReorder = list(realtime = FALSE),scrollX = TRUE,dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = I('colvis'), list(scrollX = TRUE)),
                rownames=FALSE,
                class = 'display cell-border', width=15)


    })
    }

    shinyApp <- shinyApp(ui, server)
    runApp(shinyApp, launch.browser=TRUE)
```

Reference: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#sidebar-menu-items-and-tabs